# Writing a class so it can be extended or passing blocks JAVA

Tags: java, testing

For a Java class we are writing Data structure classes and we need to write a tester class to go with them. I am going for extra credit and trying to write a single tester class that I could either extend or pass a block to for use for any testing.

Is it possible to pass a block of code for a method to run? If this is not possible or practical, what is the best way to write a class so it can be extended?

--CODE--

```
package Lab1;

/**
 * @author $RMDan
 * @date   10-Sep-2012
 * @class  Tester
 * @desc   A Tester class for testing Java classes
 *         For use in Itec 251
 */

import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class Tester {

    //members
    private String logS;

    //Constructors
    //Default to start == true

    public Tester(){
        this(true);
    }

    public Tester(Boolean start){
        if(start == true){
            this.start();
        }
    }

    public final int start(){
        int exit;
        exit = test();
        //this.displayLog();
        this.exportLog("Test_Employee.Log");
        return exit;
    }


    //Change the contents of this method to perform the test
    private int test(){

        return 0;
    }

    private void log(String message){
        this.log(message,true);
    }

    private void log(String message, boolean display){
        this.logS += message + "\n";

        if(display==true){
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

    private void displayLog(){
        System.out.print(this.logS);
    }

    private void exportLog(String file){

        try{
            String output = this.logS;
            output = output.replaceAll("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file + ".txt"))) {
                out.write(output);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Exception ");
        }

    }
}
```

Note: the final in the declaration of the start() method is there to shut up the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, "passing a block" is done by [anonymous classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm): on-the-fly implementations of an interface or class. You could use an existing interface like `Runnable`, or create your own interface that returns a value, for example:

```
interface MyTest {
    int test();
}
```

then alter your code to expect one of these:

```
public final int start(MyTest myTest) {
    ...
    exit = myTest.test();
    ...
}
```

then to use it anonymously, call your start method with an anonymous MyTest:

```
start(new MyTest() {
    public int test() {
        // do something
    } 
})l
```

You will definitely get more points for using anonymous classes!

Answer (score 2):

Overkill time: have a look at [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/), a test framework used in many real-life applications. It is designed to make it easy to implement tests. A typical test may be as small as this:

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.assert.*;
public class NameOfClassToTest {
    @Test public void nameOfSpecificTest() {
        // logic to calculate 'expected' and 'result'
        // actual example test
        assertTrue(expected.equals(result));
    }
}
```

And can be command-line executed with this:

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClass1 [...other test classes...]
```

(Although your IDE probably includes in-built support for JUnit tests).

As a teacher, I would be much more impressed if you implement a JUnit test than if you build your own testing framework from scratch...

Comment: For the current course we are just studying data structures and uses but this will be useful for next terms java course. I just wanted to find a way to learn a few things for future use hence extending or using blocks in my own class.

Comment: One of the most important lessons in programming is knowing when to avoid programming. An ounce of well-chosen external libraries avoids a ton of code-writing. People have thought long and hard on how to make testing (and logging, and so many other things that you may come up with) easy and powerful - JUnit works quite well on that regard.

Answer (score 1):

"Passing a block of code" is the same as passing a reference to an object with a known method (i.e. interface).  e.g. :

```
public class Tester {
  public static void testSomeCodeBlock(Runnable codeBlock) {
    codeBlock.run();
  }
}

Tester.testSomeCodeBlock(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    System.out.println("my code block");
  }
});
```

Alternately, if you wanted to use extension, you would have to make your `Tester.test()` method protected (and probably abstract) so the test implementations could override it.

Comment: This works perfectly for my purposes. This also shown me how I could have Overriden the test method if I wanted. Thank You